# viewing website in android browser

Tags: android, css, tablet, mobile-website, android-browser

I designed a website User Interface for mobile browsers ( Mobile version of Site )

But there is a problem in loading of my site on tablet.

[My test page](http://mahmoodkohansal.ir/hb/page2.html)

The **div id="addr_detail"** is shown in the right the of page on Tablet But in Desktop browsers it's position is out of page with below code:

```
position: absolute;
width: 350px;
right: -350px;
top: 0;
```

I want to find the reason of this difference!

Comment: I don't have a tablet to test on, but I don't see anything in the CSS that would account for the difference. Maybe there is some Javascript that changes the positioning?

Comment: I don't think so. because all of scripts are working by click on an element.